# I'm coding a page that scrolls down when a link is clicked. It appears blue after clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am coding a website that has a homepage which has a span that allows you to click it and then scroll down to a new section, the scroll works, and scrolls down but if I manually scroll back up the text appears blue and underlined. Is there any way to stop this from happening.

```
    <a class="Scroll" href="#section02"><span></span>Scroll</a>
```

This is the HTML I have used and the new sections has an ID of section02.

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 
$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 500, 'linear');
    });
});
```

This is the JS used.

```
.Scroll {
position: absolute;
height: 20px;
z-index: 20;
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
font : normal 400 20px/1 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: .1em;
text-decoration: none;
transition: opacity .3s;
}

.Scroll::after{
position: absolute;
height: 20px;
z-index: 20;
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
font : normal 400 20px/1 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
letter-spacing: .1em;
text-decoration: none;
transition: opacity .3s;
}

.Scroll:hover {
    opacity: .5;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is the CSS I have used as I thought it may have been as I had no styling after the link is clicked but the problem still occurs, although the hover style still works when the scroll is blue.

[What the scroll link looks like before.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3g9h.png)

[And what it looks like after being pressed and manually scrolling up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWySi.png)

Any help is apprecitated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.Scroll a, a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The `text-decoration: none;` should do the trick and remove the underline. If it still doesn't work add `!important` after `text-decoration` like this: `text-decoration: none !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the code for changing the color and removing the text-decoration has to be directly in the a tag

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your css to

a:visited { text-decoration: none; color: white; }

You can change the color to whatever color you want.  The text-decoration none will remove the underline.